# Python - API- pagination Graphql

Tags: python, graphql

I would like to retrieve data from an API, the problem is that it only returns 49 data each time.
I got the startCursor, hasNextPage and endCursor but I don't know how to tell the script to loop until hasNextPage=False based on the endCursor and thus have all the data for my request.
Here is the code:

```
import requests
import json

query = """
    query {
      player(slug:"lionel-andres-messi-cuccittini"){
            cards(rarities:[limited]) {
                nodes {
                    slug
                    userOwnerWithRate {
                        from
        }
        }
      pageInfo{
        startCursor
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
    }
    }
    }
  }
"""
url = 'https://api.sorare.com/graphql/'
r = requests.post(url, json={'query': query})
json_data = json.loads(r.text)
print(json_data)
```

Do you have an idea to help me get all the pages of a request please?

Comment: How is JavaScript or PHP relevant for this question?

Comment: maybe loop until `hasNextPage` in response is `False` ?

Comment: I removed JavaScript and PHP.  It must be indicated the end cursor so that it is then a false but I do not know how to indicate it in Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
query = """
    query(after:String) {
      player(slug:"lionel-andres-messi-cuccittini",after:$after){
            cards(rarities:[limited]) {
                nodes {
                    slug
                    userOwnerWithRate {
                        from
        }
        }
      pageInfo{
        startCursor
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
    }
    }
    }
  }
"""

url = 'https://api.sorare.com/graphql/'
#first query will be null
endcursor=None
r = requests.post(url, json={'query': query,'variables': None})

endcursor=r['data']['pageInfo']['endCursor']
hasnextpage=r['data']['pageInfo']['hasNextPage']
#json_data = json.loads(r.text)
out=[]
while hasnextpage!=False:
    variables={"after": endcursor}
    r = requests.post(url, json={'query': query,'variables': variables})
    #append data to list
    json_data = json.loads(r.text)
    out.extend(json_data)   

return out
```

Comment: Hello, don't share just code please, add some info about your changes, whether as comments or text above/below it.